# Not able to trigger the onlick function in the popup inside a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have written a directive in angular.js which basically draws boxes on the screen to represent the errors, each error has a popup which is a table, with each row containing some columns of information. For simplification I have kept only one href coulmn here. My requirement is when I hit the suppress href as shown below the corresponding javascipt function should get called, however in the code shown below the function **suppressKey** is never resolved. Can anybody give me some pointers as to why this is happening?

**DIRECTIVE**

```
(function () {

    var canvas;
    var directive = function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                componentId: '=',
                componentName:'=',
                siteName:'=',
                popUpHtml:'=',
                popupErrorDetails:'=',
                onMouseEnter: '&',
                onMouseLeave:'&'
            },
            templateUrl:'shared/directives/_square_draw.html',
            link : function( scope, element ) {

                var suppressKey = function() {
                    console.log( "Clicked on the suppress link" );
                }

                var generatePopupHtml = function( errors, exchangeName, onClickHandler ) {

                    var html_content = new Object();
                    html_content = '<h5 class="panel-danger">' + exchangeName + '</h5>';
                    html_content += '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" style="display=none">';

                    for (var index in errors) {

                        html_content += '<td><a href="#" onclick="suppressKey()">Suppress</a></td>';
                        html_content += '</tr>';
                    }
                    html_content += '</table>';
                    return html_content;
                }

                scope.$watch('[componentId,componentName,popupErrorDetails,siteName]',function(newValue) {
                    $('.myElement').smallipop();
                    var canvas = null;
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                    if( canvas === null ) {
                        canvas = document.getElementById( newValue[0] + newValue[3] );
                    }

                    canvas.id = newValue[0] + newValue[3];
                    canvas = document.getElementById(canvas.id);
                    var errors = newValue[2];
                    var innerHtml = generatePopupHtml( errors, newValue[1] );
                    canvas.innerHTML= '<div" id="' + canvas.id +'"><strong>' + newValue[1] + '</strong>' + '<span class="smallipop-hint">'+ innerHtml + '</span></div>';
                 }, true )

            }
        };
    };

    app.directive('squareDraw', directive);

}());
```

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<div id="canvas" class="mdd-table-responsive table-bordered mdd-table-hover myElement" style="font-size: 10px;display:'none';background-color: #F3A793;min-height: 100%;min-width:95%;border:1px solid black;">

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Hi I have tried the stuff suggested here and yet not able to get the results, while using the scope and $compile were simple to test. I am not sure about the jquery change as suggested in the post, so I am posting my code again and also the error that I am getting.

```
        var generatePopupHtml1 = function( errors, exchangeName ) {
            var htmlContent = $('<div></div>');
            htmlContent.append('<h5 class="panel-danger">' + exchangeName + '</h5>');

            var table = $('<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" style="display=none">');

            for (var index in errors) {
                table.append("<tr></tr>")
                    .append("<td></td>")
                    .append("<a href='#'>Suppress</a>")
                    .bind("click", function () {
                        console.log("bound event");
                    });
            }
            htmlContent.append(table);
            return htmlContent;
        }
```

**MODIFIED WATCH FUNCTION**

```
        scope.$watch('[componentId,componentName,popupErrorDetails,siteName]',function(newValue) {
            $('.myElement').smallipop();
            var canvas = null;
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            if( canvas === null ) {
                canvas = document.getElementById( newValue[0] + newValue[3] );
            }

            canvas.id = newValue[0] + newValue[3];
            canvas = document.getElementById(canvas.id);
            var errors = newValue[2];

            var tooltipSpan = $( '<span class="smallipop-hint"/>' );
                 tooltipSpan.append( generatePopupHtml1( errors, newValue[1] ) );

            var innerHtml = $('<div id="' + canvas.id +'"></div>');
                innerHtml.append('<strong>' + newValue[1] + '</strong>' );
                innerHtml.append( tooltipSpan );

            $('#' + canvas.id).append(innerHtml);
         }, true )
```

**ERRORS seen in the console**

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefinedjquery.smallipop.min.js:11 cbjquery.js:4430 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery.js:4116 jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
```

I have never used jquery before so I am not sure if I am missing some simple point. Thanks!

**Final Cut(the one that worked)**

```
        var suppressKey = function( user, key ) {
            console.log( "Clicked on the suppress link >>>>> " + user + " " + key );
        };

        var generatePopupHtml1 = function( errors, exchangeName ) {

            var htmlContent = $('<div></div>');

            htmlContent.append('<h5 class="panel-danger">' + exchangeName + '</h5>');
            var table = $('<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover"></table>');

            for (var index in errors) {
                var url = generateCacheDumpUrl(errors[index].id);
                table.append('<tr class="warning font-colour mdd-font-size">')
                    .append('<td><a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + errors[index].id + '</a></td>')
                    .append( '<td><a href=\"#\"' + 'id=\"' + errors[index].id + '\">Suppress</a></td>')
                    .bind("click", { id: errors[index].id  }, function(event) {
                        var data = event.data;
                        console.log( "Clicked on suppresskey " + data.id );
                        suppressKey( 'droy', data.id );
                    });
            }
            htmlContent.append(table);
            return htmlContent;
        }
```

Comment: do compile you canvas element like `$compile(canvas)(scope)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `suppressKey` function is not accessible from your table as the event is not bound to your anchor element.

Change your `var generatePopupHtml` function to build up the table by creating the actual elements instead of using string concatenation like so:

```
var htmlContent = $('<div></div>');
 htmlContent.append('<h5 class="panel-danger">' + exchangeName + '</h5>');

 var table = $('<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" style="display=none">');

 for (var index in errors) {
    var row = $("<tr></tr>")
        .append("<td></td>")
        .append("<a href='#'>Suppress</a>");

    row.find("a").bind("click", function () {
        console.log("bound event");
    });
    table.append(row);
 }

 htmlContent.append(table);
 return htmlContent;
```

A quick fix would be to wrap your table html and `.bind` the anchor tag with a click event.

```
return $(html_content).find("a").bind("click", function () {
    console.log("Clicked on the suppress link");
});
```

Comment: I still see the jquery error in the console and whenever I click the link the entire page reloads. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Hi @deb. Please have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/sLsxgbez/ . I've modified the code a little bit and tried to replicate what you're trying to achieve. You will notice that the click does a console.log. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the suppressKey function to the scope to make it accessible. The suppressKey function you've defined is basically private and can't be accessed outside the link function.

```
scope.suppressKey = function () {
    console.log( "Clicked on the suppress link" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to [**compile**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) element which you are added by directive. You always to compile newly added element using $compile service so that element will get register to DOM.

Just add below line after assigning `canvas.innerHTML`(First add `$compile` dependence on your directive)

```
$compile(canvas)(scope)
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.